# How to get data from database in Pie Chart?

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I created a pie chart in android using MPAndroidChart , i want to get data from mysql database and parse it in my pie chart.
Please , how can i do that. Any help would be considerable.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR You can't, or you shouldn't, do that on Android since then you will have login credentials for database on client app and that is not good.

If you are already familiar with Java I would recommend building REST API with some implementation of JAX-RS specification like [Jersey](https://jersey.github.io/). This API will query database and serve your data trough HTTP and than you could easily connect it to your Android app with libraries like Retrofit.

Comment: How can i do that ? do you have any code for that ?

Comment: It's a separate project so I can't just write this in a few minutes.

Comment: Then , how can you help me with this , please